# Furigana rendering options as of 2017/10/16

Tags: bug, feature-request, furigana

Why have they changed again?  I have mine set to the following:

[image]

The popups work fine when I hover a kanji, but the furigana is shown all the time regardless of the popup option.  Here is how the following text renders for me, and how it looks when I hover it

> encoded here as [日本語]​{にほんご}

[日本語]{にほんご}

Normal rendering:

[image]

When I hover it:

[image]

Why is it there in the normal rendering?!  I don't want it there.  I want it turned off, and only show when I hover.  This used to work fine, but now it's changed again.  I seem to remember more options than just **Width adjust** and **Popups**.  Where did they go?

Having furigana show all the time is a big distraction to me, especially in posts where it's used on many words.  Can we get all the old options back please?